# <img> tag parallax image not background-image: attached in css

Tags: jquery, css

I tried to make parallax effect on  tag. but it is not working.
http://prntscr.com/rbq4ha
I need to make the image as parallax like the linked image.
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a container element and add a background image to the container with a specific height. Then use the `background-attachment: fixed` to create the actual parallax effect. The other background properties are used to center and scale the image perfectly/
Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://miro.medium.com/max/2046/1*ZJuc_2TsDElu6Gtg_KxiEg.png");

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is an [easy tutorial](https://medium.com/@emmanelson_72964/the-easy-way-to-create-parallax-scrolling-eb708d434a4a) how to create parallax scrolling.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but I want to make that in img tag. http://prntscr.com/rbqfzg

Comment: Edit your question with an updated version: add the code you created so the responses can be helpful to you.

Comment: <div class="one-half last">
                <img src="http://bediasbank.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/tradition-image.jpg">            </div>

Comment: Remove the `<img>` tag and apply the `.parallax` style I gave you in the example above to your second `<div>`

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it did help you. Thank you.